# Passing fields parameter to AMS JSONAPI serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I want to set the fields with a value being passed through the URL.  For example right now I can do this:

```
def index
  authors = Author.all
  render json: authors, include: params[:include], fields: {authors: [:id], posts: [:title]}
end
```

And this works just how I want it to.  It comes back with only the author's id and the title of their posts.  What I would like to do is something like this:

```
def index
  authors = Author.all
  render json: authors, include: params[:include], fields: params[:fields]
end
```

And it would do the same thing as before when I use this URL: http://localhost:3000/authors?include=posts&fields[author]=[id]&fields[posts]=[title]
However, when I do that I get all the fields on authors and all the fields on posts.

Here is my serializers for reference:

```
class AuthorSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name
  has_many :posts
end

class PostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :title, :text
  belongs_to :author
  has_many :comments
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The "fields" part of the URL will result in Rails `params` being like this:

```
{
  "fields" => {
    "author" => "[id]",
    "posts" => "[title]"
  }
}
```

as you can see there are [] around your attributes, so you need to remove those.

Secondly if you want to be able to be able to request multiple attributes off your `Post` model, i.e pass `title,text` in your URL. You'll also need to convert `'title,text'` to an array before passing it all to the `render` method "fields" argument.

*(Note: This can change in future versions of Active Model Serializers, since the JsonApi adapter is still under development..)*